# How do I create custom local notifications in React Native?

Tags: android, notifications, react-native

I need to create several types of notifications but I have no idea which libraries could help me to create custom layout.

I've found that modal notifications are similar to Firebase in-app-messaging, but I need this functionality to work without internet connection. Also I know that https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/wiki/Android:-Layout-Customization has something helpful but guide is not full and seems like it won't solve the problem with modal notification.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwmXI.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have many actually.

Most people use this one: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#local-notifications

Then you also have Firebase notifications: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/displaying-notifications

And then my personal favorite is OneSignal which is free, has more features than Firebase and can be easily be integrated to send push messages, although it does not support local notifications just yet: www.onesignal.com

Good luck!